# javascript - client_id on WL.init()

Tags: javascript, api, onedrive

This is my first time using the Sky Drive API for javascript. I'm a little confused on where to get the credentials for the init method:

```
WL.init({
        client_id: APP_CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
        scope: "wl.signin",
        response_type: "token"
    });
```

where can I get the value for `client_id` and what are the possible values for `redirect_uri`? I really need those answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For instructions on integrating with the Microsoft SSO using HTML/JavaScript see http://blogs.windows.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2011/06/29/developers-just-a-few-lines-of-javascript-connects-your-site-to-windows-live.aspx

To get the client_id you need to register your app here - https://account.live.com/developers/applications